# Too many shards on node for attribute: [rack], required per attribute: [1], node count: [2], leftover: [0]

Tags: elasticsearch

Got the error when I tried to allocate unassigned secondary shards to a node.

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "remote_transport_exception",
        "reason": "[10.0.2.17][10.0.2.17:9300][cluster:admin/reroute]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "[allocate] allocation of [vts_companydirectory_20170625_2040][1] on node {10.0.2.34}{atDVd6lEQTiuBitCsqYqBA}{10.0.2.34}{10.0.2.34:9300}{max_local_storage_nodes=1, rack=rack.10-0-2, master=true} is not allowed, reason: [YES(shard is not allocated to same node or host)][YES(node passes include/exclude/require filters)][YES(target node version [2.3.3] is same or newer than source node version [2.3.3])][YES(primary is already active)][YES(enough disk for shard on node, free: [1.3tb])][YES(allocation disabling is ignored)][NO(too many shards on node for attribute: [rack], required per attribute: [1], node count: [2], leftover: [0])][YES(shard count under index limit [10] and node limit [-1] of total shards per node)][YES(below shard recovery limit of [10])][YES(allocation disabling is ignored)][YES(shard not primary or relocation disabled)]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have shard allocation awareness enabled.
See [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/allocation-awareness.html).

Elasticsearch tries not to allocate primary and replica shards on Nodes with the same value for a specific attribute ("rack" in your case).

You are getting this error because Elasticsearch's shard allocation awareness prevented allocation of the replica shard of that index on the node you specified as other nodes with same value for the "rack" attribute ("rack" = "rack.10-0-2") currently have the primary (or other) replica shard allocated to them

Try allocating this shard to another node whose value for the "rack" attribute is not same as the one u tried allocating to.